# Am I dealing with an asyncio task ignoring CancelledError correctly?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm not asking how to cancel such task. It is not possible and it it is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33578893/5378816

My concern is this change in [wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for):

> Changed in version 3.7: When aw is cancelled due to a timeout,
>   wait_for waits for aw to be cancelled. Previously, it raised
>   asyncio.TimeoutError immediately.

Don't get me wrong, I like it, it is an improvement.

However, this program will now hang in `wait_for` (Python 3.7):

```
import asyncio

async def uncancellable():
    while True:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(99)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("sorry!")

TIMEOUT = 1.0

async def test():
    task = asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(uncancellable())
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(task, TIMEOUT)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("timeout")

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```

An uncancellable task is a programming error. But if I need to be [defensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), how do I prevent the `wait_for` from hanging indefinitely?

I tried this. First timeout: before cancelling, second timeout: before giving up.

```
await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.wait_for(task, TIMEOUT1), TIMEOUT1+TIMEOUT2)
```

There is one tiny issue I don't much care about. When it raises `asyncio.TimeoutError` I cannot tell if it happened at first or at the second timeout. Basically I think it works, but is it really correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I need to be defensive, how do I prevent the wait_for from
>   hanging indefinitely?

I don't think to consider each task as potentially uncancellable is a good idea.

Usually you just assume this situation won't happen and it's ok because, yes, uncancellable task is a programming error and it's not a kind of error that you expect to see often. Same way you usually don't expect some inner code will suppress `KeyboardInterrupt` or [any other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797463/1113207) `BaseException`.

There's nothing wrong in expecting third-party code to follow some contracts (like in example above or, let's say not randomly to call `sys.exit()`). Otherwise you'll have to write **much** more code and probably still not cover all possible cases.